# How to read HttpRequest data sent from client, on server

Tags: html, dart

How do i read HttpRequest data sent by POST method from client, on the server, in Dart?

I send a message from the client like this:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081";
request.open("POST", url, async: false);

String data = 'hello from client'; 
request.send(data);
```

On server i am catching the request like this:

```
HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8081).then((server) {
server.listen((HttpRequest request) {

//DATA SHOULD BE READ HERE 



});
});
```

But i cant figure out how to actually read the data... There is not data property in HttpRequest nor anything else...

EDIT This is how i get the answer now:

```
HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8081).then((server) {
server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
  //DATA SHOULD BE READ HERE 
  print("got it");
  print(request.method);
  if(request.method == "POST") {
    print("got it 2");
    List<int> dataBody = new List<int>();
    request.listen(dataBody.addAll, onDone: () {
      var postData = new String.fromCharCodes(dataBody);
      print(postData);
      });
    }
 });
});
```

But for some reason the request.method is not "POST" but "OPTIONS", and if i change to `if(request.method == "OPTIONS")` , then print(postData) will still return nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the handling of POST data is a little difficult. But essentially the HttpRequest itself has to be 'listened' to. [HttpRequest is a stream itself](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html). In particular it's a `Stream<List<int>>`. So basically your data may be passed to your HttpRequest as multiple `List<int>`'s. So we need to reconstruct the data then convert it into a string (assuming you're expecting a string, not binary data, etc). Here's more or less what I do:

```dart
HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8081).then((server) {
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
  if(request.method == "POST") {
    List<int> dataBody = new List<int>();
    request.listen(dataBody.addAll, onDone: () {
      var postData = new String.fromCharCodes(dataBody);
      // Do something with the data now.
    });
  }
  request.response.close();
});
```

Note that the `request.listen(dataBody.AddAll, ...)` basically calls [List.addAll()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#addAll) each time data is to the server (in cases of larger data or multi-part forms it may not come all at once). This ensures we buffer it all until the stream indicates it is 'done' In which case we can now do something with the data we received, like convert it to a string.

Comment: thank you for your help but this did not work. i updated my original post with the info...

Comment: I've also updated my code. The Options header is the client (web browser) asking the server what functionality it supports. In this (I'm assuming test case) you can discard it, as it will then send the POST request itself. Unfortunately I had previously forgotten to close the stream so that didn't occur.
More details on HTTP request types can be found here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: i dont have a close() method in HttpRequest

Comment: Sorry my bad, was going too fast. Updated again. I forgot to close the response not the request itself ;)

Comment: now im getting Failed to load resource: Origin http://127.0.0.1:3030 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
  http://127.0.0.1:8081/
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8081/. Origin http://127.0.0.1:3030 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: It looks like your loading a script with one resource and the server as a different one. Basically this is a security setting for all browsers. You need to enable "Cross Origin Resource Sharing" or alternatively host your script by your server project. See comments/response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456591/cors-with-dart-how-do-i-get-it-to-work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StringDecoder to tranform from "List of Int" to "String" from the HttpRequest. Since no matter if you send json, plain text, or png, Dart always send data in form of 
"List of Int" to the server.Another means is to use the Streams (http://www.dartlang.org/articles/feet-wet-streams/) tested on Heroku Steam v0.6.2 Dart Editor 0.4.3_r20602 Dat SDK 0.4.3.5_r26062

For example,

the client:

```
 import 'dart:html';
 import 'dart:json' as Json;
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'dart:uri';
 final String data = 'Hello World!';
 void _sendPNG(String pngData) {
 HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR
 // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
 request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) 
 {
 if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
 (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)) {
 // data saved OK.
 print(request.responseText); // output the response from the server
 }
                  }
 );
 // POST the data to the server Async
 print('Sending Photos to the server...');
 var url = "/png";
 request.open("POST", url);
 request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
 request.send(data);
 }
```

the server:

```
 import 'dart:io';
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'dart:json' as Json;
 import "package:stream/stream.dart";
 import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
 import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
 import 'package:rikulo_commons/mirrors.dart';
 void receivePNG(HttpConnect connect){
 var request = connect.request;
 var response = connect.response;
 if(request.uri.path == '/png' && request.method == 'POST')
  {
   String png='';
   response.write('The server received png request!');
   //read incoming List<int> data from request and use StringDecoder to transform   incoming data to string
   var stream = request.transform(new StringDecoder());
   stream.listen((value){
   print(value);
   //Hello World!
  }
  else
  {
   response.write('error');
   response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
   connect.close();
   }
  }
```

configure.dart

```
 var _mapping = {
  "/": home,
  "/png": receivePNG,
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this useful example with client/side code

[GitHub json send to server Example](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-up-and-running-book/blob/master/code/ch03/ch03_3_html/web/json-send-to-server.dart)

```dart
// XXX: Dart Editor thinks this is OK, but I haven't run it.

import 'dart:html';

String encodeMap(Map data) {
  return data.keys.map((k) {
    return '${Uri.encodeComponent(k)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(data[k])}';
  }).join('&');
}

loadEnd(HttpRequest request) {
  if (request.status != 200) {
    print('Uh oh, there was an error of ${request.status}');
    return;
  } else {
    print('Data has been posted');
  }
}

main() {
  var dataUrl = '/registrations/create';
  var data = {'dart': 'fun', 'editor': 'productive'};
  var encodedData = encodeMap(data);

  var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open('POST', dataUrl);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 
                               'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((e) => loadEnd(httpRequest));
  httpRequest.send(encodedData);
}
```